# How to get started with Zend Framework developemt

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hai

First of all Thanks...
 I have a downloaded Zend framework C:\wamp\zend I changed include path to php.ini to

C:\wamp\zend, I seen this in my php info.  I think the include path is correct. Still I have lot of doubt, where I start my work in zend framework? Which are the steps??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to have a single Zend framework instance for your entire server, as it's possible that different applications will want to use different versions. Although in your case it probably doesn't matter much. :)

As for getting started with Zend, there's a perfectly good [tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart) on the Zend site you can read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tutorial and/or some documentation, especially if starting from scratch, here are a couple of links that could interest you :

- [Survive The Deep End!](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/) : a free electronic-book about ZF

  - It's still work in progress,
  - but the existing chapters are quite good -- and they will allow you to start, at least.
- [The official Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart) : it's short, you can study it for something like 2 to 4 hours, I'd say, and it'll allow you to develop a really simple/basic/quick application.

Those might be helpful, for you to start.

And here are some other resources *(there are quite a lot of resources about ZF, actually)* :

- The official [Reference Guide](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/) -- not quite perfect as a starting point, but it contains the documentation of every classes of the Framework, and most of their useful public methods ; you'll work with this one really often, I guess !
- A [couple of screencasts](http://zendframework.com/docs/screencasts)

  - There are also [webinars](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework), and a couple [podcasts](http://devzone.zend.com/search/results?q=%27zend+framework%27+podcast)
- More advanced, there are interesting articles about [ZF on devzone](http://devzone.zend.com/tag/Zend%20Framework)
- Of course, you can find books about ZF, too. For instance :

  - [Beginning Zend Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218258)
  - [Zend Framework in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988320)