# How to learn Zend

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to learn Zend. I'm having trouble understanding the concept of MVC. Please give some good tutorials.Help me...

Comment: If you do not fully understand the concept of MVC I'd suggest codeigniter, zend is quite complex .. codeigniter has very nice documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to learn Zend Framework, I would recommend the e-book *(still work in progress, but the 10 first chapters should already help quite a bit)* called [Zend Framework: Survive The Deep End!](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/).

There is definitly some nice stuff in there -- and there are some chapters that say more about MVC than I saw in other manuals / tutorials.

Also, you might want to take a look at Rob Allen's tutorial : [Getting Started with Zend Framework 1.10](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

And, of course, don't forget the official [reference guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/), and [Zend's QuickStart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links to get you started:

[SO related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437180/how-to-get-started-with-zend-framework-developemt)

[Zend Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

And, as Pascal said, check the e-book he suggested.